# Javascript: return statement before and after function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on the code below and it returns `true` if every value in the array is positive. I have it working, but I would love clarification on why two return statements are required. What are the mechanics of the two returns vs. just the first?

```js
function checkPositive(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
 return arr.every(function(X){
  return X > 0;
})

  // Only change code above this line
}
checkPositive([1, 2, 3, -4, 5]);
console.log(checkPositive([1, 2, 3, -4, 5])); //false
```

Comment: Two functions, two returns.

Comment: A function will execute but not return. If you want the value from the inner function you need to either assign to a variable or return the response..

Answer (score 2):

```
return arr.every(function(X){
  return X > 0;
})
```

The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

So `return X > 0;` is the test case return: function return inside `every()`.
Based on that returns (that return will be existed for every element), `every()` function returns `true` when all inside function returns return `true`

and returns `false` even if one inside function returns `false`.

So that two returns are existed.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing good. I will try to explain as simply as possible.

`every` is a handy array method that you use to check if all the elements in the array pass a certain condition. It returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`).

So `every` takes a callback as an argument and it invokes that callback for each element in the array. And it checks the `return` statement inside the callback that you have passed in as an argument. And if the `return` statement inside the callback, returns `true` or a truthy value for each element in the array, `every` returns `true`. Returns `false` otherwise.

What you are doing is, you are returning (first `return` statement) the invocation of `every` from inside the `checkPositive` function. So `every` gets called and it checks whether the callback is returning a truthy value for each element in the array (second `return` statement). And then it returns `true` or `false` to your first `return` statement. Which returns it out of the function.

Hope that makes sense.

(JavaScript functions return `undefined` if you do not explicitly return something.)